# how to get the next given parent

Tags: jquery

If you got a TD in a table, how can you then get the parent TABLE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you want `.closest()`:

```
var $table = $("yourTdSelector").closest("table");
```

`.parents()` will return all tables that are ancestor, so if you had a table within a table, you'll get both `<table>` elements with no reference as to which is the actual closest parent.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [jQuery.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
var $table = $("yourTdSelector").parents("table");
```

**EDIT:**

Actually, disregard this, [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is indeed the better option here (as shown in the other answers).

Answer (score 1):

There's also `$('td').closest('table')`: http://api.jquery.com/closest/